# Is it okay to ask my boss a laptop or computer loan?

Tags: communication, salary, unprofessional-behavior, freelancing, clients

I was considering to ask from my boss for 2 years even though he wasn't offering it. He outsourced his Customer Service to our country and he was nice all the time however with very few benefits, and anything that he may offer may be changed by him without prior notice. Just like paid- time off. He may give us leave pay but no assurance. It depends on his move. Regarding benefits, I have raised this with him, where we need to streamline employees' benefits and guidelines but he just brushed it off. Fine, his call maybe he is not ready yet. If I would buy the laptop by myself I guess it's fine but I thought I should ask since I have been using my old laptop for this work only and other things that I do, side gigs, personal - I use a different laptop. Now, I believe it's due for retirement and I need an upgrade. I want it to be as simple as he is loaning me a computer an I repay it in 2 mos without interest but if its going to look unprofessional, I won't. thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you prefer this instead of asking for payment options at your preferred Laptop Retailer? Some offer 12 month payments and similar, so given that you mention you intend to pay in 2 months then it's very likely your retailer can accept 2 payments.

Comment: I just thought it's more practical since retailers here charge really high-interest rates.

Comment: I've seen Visa payment options for 12 months without interests and I'm in a "3rd world country"... Surely a 2 month payment will be very affordable even if with interests. Either that or save for 2 months and buy it up front (just as you would have payed your employer in 2 months).

Comment: @Noreen, I think you should ask this question on https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ Also, if you need to ask for a personal loan for a computer, then it could mean you're not charging nearly enough money for your work, or it could mean that you need to ask for a bigger retainer upfront for your future clients. Also, the fact that you have to depend on the personal whims and mood of this one client is a bad sign. Hopefully, you can find yourself a better client.

Comment: Welcome to workplace.SE. Unfortunately, your question is unclear, and may be closed.
In particular: Do you want your boss to loan you money so you can buy a new computer? Or do you want to borrow a computer? If it's money - why do you want to borrow from your boss, and not from a bank or from the shop where you buy it? Are you an employee of the company, or a freelancer? Finally, have you considered asking for a company laptop for your work?
Could you edit to clarify? Thanks!

Comment: I considered asking for a loan to buy a laptop but if he can give me a company laptop that is a good idea as well.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yea, I am a freelancer but he hired me 2 years ago to work for him full-time. I guess you're right, I'm not charging enough. I tried requesting for a raise but he said based on current market, my pay is fair.

Comment: @Noreen, He has a right to say no, but you have the right to walk away as well. Some clients are just unreasonable. And if you're not saying no to potential clients a few times a year, then it means you're probably underpricing your services. Also, can't you buy a cheap Chromebook or something? What software tools do you need for this work?

Answer (score 3):

> but if its going to look unprofessional

Asking for a personal loan is unprofessional. You should either buy it yourself, or ask for a suitable machine to be purchased for you at company expense.

Comment: "*Asking for a personal loan is unprofessional.*": not everywhere. I once worked for a big company that was offering some very interesting benefits, like being guarantor for personal loans, for rents, for many things related to personal growth and others... They had agreements with companies in many areas. And it was not the only company to do that.

Comment: @OldPadawan I don't see were the OP's boss is anythng like that. I'm not answering a question about some place you once worked at

Comment: That second option is the really professional one. Proper employers will expect that they're going to provide staff with the equipment they need to do their work (yeah, I know...)

Answer (score 3):

I'm presuming from the question you aren't a native english speaker - so there may be some cultural aspects - where you are exactly might change the answer.

The general answer is that so long as you have a good relationship with your Boss, your Boss trusts you and (most importantly) *you trust yourself*, then this should be fine.

I've 'purchased' items through my Company before - essentially because I got a better rate through the agreement we had with our supplier than I would as a retail store - saving me something like $2-300.

The main part is though making sure you can honor your obligations - if you've committed to paying it off in 2 months, you had better be sure you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for personal use:

The professional approach, if your company would do it, would be to ask the *company* for an advance on your wages, not your boss. They will probably say no unless you give them a good reason, but in a small company they might agree.

More professional would be to save up for it, if this isn't immediately critical. Or put it on your own credit card, and pay the interest as a penalty for not being able to wait.

If it's for company use, the company decides whether you need it, and if so they pay for it. If they don't think you need it, see above re personal use.

Note that many companies will *not* let you use your own machine for company work, or will insist that you manage it to company security standards, so ask before putting company data on a machine the company does not own.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between the two companies is not clear in this question.

It states "outsourced [..] Customer Service to our country". Typically, that is not done as person to person but as company to company. Thus, asking the client company to provide equipment for the company that is outsourced to is a contract issue not a personal issue.

You are hired by a specific company. That company has the responsibility to provide you with equipment. The client does not. Now that company may negotiate with the client to increase the payment rate so that they can upgrade their equipment.

In this question, the client is called "boss", yet that is not the true relationship. Your boss is the person who owns the company in your country and negotiated and signed the contract with the client. That is the person to ask about equipment.

And, yes, it is not a good idea to use personal equipment in a business relationship.